# Ansible Plugin File with JinJa2 conditional

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am putting together a config file for the AWS.ec2 inventory plugin.  I am trying to set the `ansible_host` variable based on if the particular VM has a public IP address assigned to it or not.

When I use:

```
ansible_host: public_ip_address
```

It works fine (assuming there is a public IP) but when I try to put logic in there, it doesn't set the var at all.

```
ansible_host: "{% if public_ip_address is defined %} public_ip_address {% else %} private_ip_address {% endif %}"
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Is there any error in the output? Can you try the form `{{ public_ip_address if public_ip_address is defined else private_ip_address }}`? (if not ok, you could also try without the curly braces)

Comment: No error messages, it just excludes the `ansible_host` variable completely.  I will try and give your suggesting a try this evening and see how it goes....Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a ton @zigarn

```
public_ip_address if public_ip_address is defined else private_ip_address
```